# What are the limitations involved in a Two Samples Independent t-Test?

Tags: t-test, sample

I have to discuss the limitations involved with an independent samples t-test. I have stated that the test was limited by the amount of data that was provided. (Samples of larger amount of values would more accurately represent the population).

However I am unsure about what else I would discuss? Would the "limitations" refer more to the topic I am discussing? or are there particular limitations in regards to Independent t-tests?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can examine the assumptions of t-test, so the limitations are clear. When data violates the assumptions, t-test might not have reliability.

Assumptions include:

- the scale of measurement. The assumption for a t-test is that the scale of measurement applied to the data collected follows a continuous or ordinal scale, such as the scores for an IQ test. (Investopedia)
- random sampling. The data is collected from a representative, randomly selected portion of the total population.
- data is normally distributed.
- the two population have the same variance. This can be adjusted though.